# Wymeditor across subdomains. (Cross site permission issue.)

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, xss, wymeditor

I have wymeditor on sub1.domain.com, which is accessed by a page on sub2.domains.com.

This line gives an error:

```
var styles = this._doc.styleSheets[0];
```

> Permission denied for http://removed.example.com to get property
>   HTMLDocument.styleSheets from http://removed2.example.com.

I am assuming this is a cross site scripting restriction, but I would like to srve my media from a  different domain. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the line `document.domain = "domain.com";` in both pages, replacing `domain.com` with whatever your actual domain name is.

Comment: In the html as well as javascript as well? The javascript is third party, so I would like to not modify it if I can.

Comment: It needs to be in the JavaScript for each page, at a point before any code that starts trying to talk to the other window.

Comment: Wym editor does not work well on cross domains since it depends on AJAX to load skins and other components. Anyone fixed this ?

Comment: skins.js can be loaded with Cross origin resources sharing (CORS) supported by AWS S3