# Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to set the 'domain' property on 'Document': 'app.herokuapp.com' is not a suffix of ''.

Tags: javascript, cordova

I'm developing a Phonegap app, in order to avoid CORS protection, thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206586/wymeditor-across-subdomains-cross-site-permission-issue), I've tried changing document domain in my javascript file.

Now I'm getting this error

```
Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to set the 'domain' property on 'Document': 'app.herokuapp.com' is not a suffix of ''.
```

How can I make it so my phonegap app have domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [django-crossdomainxhr-middleware.py](https://gist.github.com/barrabinfc/426829) solved my problem!!